CMake Cannot Find SDL2TTF package
I installed SDL2ttf for a project and SDL2_image and it seems that cmake cannot find the package only of SDL2ttf although i applied the same logic. Specifically i downloaded the libraries, i created a FindSL2_image and FindSL2ttf cmake file, updated the CmakeLists.txt and for some reason SDL2_image seted up smoothly but SDL2ttf didnt and now i get this error:
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.4/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL2TTF (missing: SDL2TTF_LIBRARY SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.4/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake_modules/FindSDL2TTF.cmake:163 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)

thats the updated CmakeList.txt and FindSLD2TTF.cmake
CMakeList.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(Projects)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/ ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(SDL2_PATH "C:/libs/SDL2-2.30.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32")
set(SDL2_IMAGE_PATH "C:/libs/SDL2_image-2.8.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32")
set(SDL2_TTF_PATH "C:/libs/SDL2_ttf-2.22.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

configure_file(images/Tic-tac-toe.bmp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/images/Tic-Tac-Toe.bmp COPYONLY)
configure_file(images/circle-1.png.png ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/images/circle-1.png.png COPYONLY)
configure_file(images/X.png ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/images/X.png COPYONLY)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2TTF REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(Projects main.cpp
        TicTacToe.h
        TicTacToe.cpp
        O_Symol.h
        X_Symbol.h
        O_Symol.cpp
        X_Symbol.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES})type here

FindSDL2TTF.cmake:
# Locate SDL2 library
# This module defines
# SDL2_LIBRARY, the name of the library to link against
# SDL2_FOUND, if false, do not try to link to SDL2
# SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR, where to find SDL.h
#
# This module responds to the the flag:
# SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY
# If this is defined, then no SDL2main will be linked in because
# only applications need main().
# Otherwise, it is assumed you are building an application and this
# module will attempt to locate and set the the proper link flags
# as part of the returned SDL2_LIBRARY variable.
#
# Don't forget to include SDLmain.h and SDLmain.m your project for the
# OS X framework based version. (Other versions link to -lSDL2main which
# this module will try to find on your behalf.) Also for OS X, this
# module will automatically add the -framework Cocoa on your behalf.
#
#
# Additional Note: If you see an empty SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP in your configuration
# and no SDL2_LIBRARY, it means CMake did not find your SDL2 library
# (SDL2.dll, libsdl2.so, SDL2.framework, etc).
# Set SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP to point to your SDL2 library, and configure again.
# Similarly, if you see an empty SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY, you should set this value
# as appropriate. These values are used to generate the final SDL2_LIBRARY
# variable, but when these values are unset, SDL2_LIBRARY does not get created.
#
#
# $SDL2DIR is an environment variable that would
# correspond to the ./configure --prefix=$SDL2DIR
# used in building SDL2.
# l.e.galup  9-20-02
#
# Modified by Eric Wing.
# Added code to assist with automated building by using environmental variables
# and providing a more controlled/consistent search behavior.
# Added new modifications to recognize OS X frameworks and
# additional Unix paths (FreeBSD, etc).
# Also corrected the header search path to follow "proper" SDL guidelines.
# Added a search for SDL2main which is needed by some platforms.
# Added a search for threads which is needed by some platforms.
# Added needed compile switches for MinGW.
#
# On OSX, this will prefer the Framework version (if found) over others.
# People will have to manually change the cache values of
# SDL2_LIBRARY to override this selection or set the CMake environment
# CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH to modify the search paths.
#
# Note that the header path has changed from SDL2/SDL.h to just SDL.h
# This needed to change because "proper" SDL convention
# is #include "SDL.h", not <SDL2/SDL.h>. This is done for portability
# reasons because not all systems place things in SDL2/ (see FreeBSD).

#=============================================================================
# Copyright 2003-2009 Kitware, Inc.
#
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD License (the "License");
# see accompanying file Copyright.txt for details.
#
# This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
# implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the License for more information.
#=============================================================================
# (To distribute this file outside of CMake, substitute the full
#  License text for the above reference.)

SET(SDL2TTF_SEARCH_PATHS
        ~/Library/Frameworks
        /Library/Frameworks
        /usr/local
        /usr
        /sw # Fink
        /opt/local # DarwinPorts
        /opt/csw # Blastwave
        /opt
)

FIND_PATH(SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR SDL_ttf.h
        HINTS
        $ENV{SDL2TTFDIR}
        PATH_SUFFIXES include/SDL2 include
        PATHS ${SDL2TTF_SEARCH_PATHS}
)

FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP
        NAMES SDL2_ttf
        HINTS
        $ENV{SDL2TTFDIR}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
        PATHS ${SDL2TTF_SEARCH_PATHS}
)

IF(NOT SDL2TTF_BUILDING_LIBRARY)
    IF(NOT ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR} MATCHES ".framework")
        # Non-OS X framework versions expect you to also dynamically link to
        # SDL2TTFmain. This is mainly for Windows and OS X. Other (Unix) platforms
        # seem to provide SDL2TTFmain for compatibility even though they don't
        # necessarily need it.
        FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2TTFMAIN_LIBRARY
                NAMES SDL2_ttf
                HINTS
                $ENV{SDL2TTFDIR}
                PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                PATHS ${SDL2TTF_SEARCH_PATHS}
        )
    ENDIF(NOT ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR} MATCHES ".framework")
ENDIF(NOT SDL2TTF_BUILDING_LIBRARY)

# SDL2TTF may require threads on your system.
# The Apple build may not need an explicit flag because one of the
# frameworks may already provide it.
# But for non-OSX systems, I will use the CMake Threads package.
IF(NOT APPLE)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Threads)
ENDIF(NOT APPLE)

# MinGW needs an additional library, mwindows
# It's total link flags should look like -lmingw32 -lSDL2TTFmain -lSDL2TTF -lmwindows
# (Actually on second look, I think it only needs one of the m* libraries.)
IF(MINGW)
    SET(MINGW32_LIBRARY mingw32 CACHE STRING "mwindows for MinGW")
ENDIF(MINGW)

IF(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP)
    # For SDL2TTFmain
    IF(NOT SDL2TTF_BUILDING_LIBRARY)
        IF(SDL2TTFMAIN_LIBRARY)
            SET(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2TTFMAIN_LIBRARY} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP})
        ENDIF(SDL2TTFMAIN_LIBRARY)
    ENDIF(NOT SDL2TTF_BUILDING_LIBRARY)

    # For OS X, SDL2TTF uses Cocoa as a backend so it must link to Cocoa.
    # CMake doesn't display the -framework Cocoa string in the UI even
    # though it actually is there if I modify a pre-used variable.
    # I think it has something to do with the CACHE STRING.
    # So I use a temporary variable until the end so I can set the
    # "real" variable in one-shot.
    IF(APPLE)
        SET(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP} "-framework Cocoa")
    ENDIF(APPLE)

    # For threads, as mentioned Apple doesn't need this.
    # In fact, there seems to be a problem if I used the Threads package
    # and try using this line, so I'm just skipping it entirely for OS X.
    IF(NOT APPLE)
        SET(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    ENDIF(NOT APPLE)

    # For MinGW library
    IF(MINGW)
        SET(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP ${MINGW32_LIBRARY} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP})
    ENDIF(MINGW)

    # Set the final string here so the GUI reflects the final state.
    SET(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP} CACHE STRING "Where the SDL2TTF Library can be found")
    # Set the temp variable to INTERNAL so it is not seen in the CMake GUI
    SET(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP "${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
ENDIF(SDL2TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP)

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SDL2TTF REQUIRED_VARS SDL2TTF_LIBRARY SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR)


Why do you expect FindSDL2TTF.cmake script to find your SDL2ttf installation? In CMakeLists.txt you set SDL2_TTF_PATH variable, but it is not used in the script.

Can you explain further, i dont understand what do you mean is not used in the script?

If you have SDL2 ttf installed in non-standard location (technically, on Windows all locations are non-standard), then you need to give a hint to FindSDL2TTF.cmake script about that location. In your CMakeLists.txt you attempted to specify the hint via SDL2_TTF_PATH variable. But this variable is not used in the FindSDL2TTF.cmake  script, so the script doesn't get your hint. The script accepts hints via environment variable SDL2TTFDIR, which should be set to the SDL2 ttf installation directory. The variable could be set in CMakeLists.txt via set(ENV{SDL2TTFDIR} ...) notation.

I understand thank you so much. So if i set the variable like that "set(ENV{SDL2TTFDIR} C:/path/to/SDL2_ttf-2.22.0) " would the problem be solved or need to modify something else?
